# for 文を含むコードでエラー: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

0.1を10回足しても1にならないことを確認しようとコードを書きましたが動きません。
何がまずいんでしょうか？

```
a = 0
for i in range(10):
a += 0.1
a
```

anacondaというソフトからJupiter Notebookというものを呼び出して使っています。
先ほどのものは一度消して初めからやり直したところ以下のように表示されました。
aが何かおかしいんでしょうか？

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13580\1575381174.py", line 3
    a += 0.1
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: 動かないという状況の詳細な内容を記述してください。エラーメッセージが表示されているなら、その表示されたまま全文をテキストで提示してください。また実行している環境や手順についての情報も記述してください。ちなみに表示されたまま入力しているとすると、`for`ループの中の`a += 0.1`にインデントが不足しています。それからインタプリタ上で逐次入力しているなら、最後の`a`を入力する前に、`for`ループの入力が終了したことを示す、行の先頭でのEnterだけの改行入力が必要です。

Comment: '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

Comment: エラーメッセージって上記ですかね。
Runを押してもOutが何も出てこない状況です。

Comment: > 行の先頭でのEnterだけの改行入力が必要です。
下のaとの間に空欄の行が一行必要ということですかね？

Comment: そのエラーメッセージで検索するとこれらの記事 ['_xsrf' argument missing from POSTエラーの単純な対処法](https://system-medicine.blog.jp/archives/12482649.html), [jupyter notebookの'_xsrf' argument missing from POSTの解決法](https://oknzkzk.com/2021/08/21/jupyter-notebook%E3%81%AE_xsrf-argument-missing-from-post%E3%81%AE%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E6%B3%95/) が出てきますが、それは問題が発生した後で何か別の事をしようとしているのでは？ 最初の動かない時のエラーメッセージをコメントではなく質問記事を編集して追記してください。あと実行環境や作業手順についても追記しておいてください。

Answer (score 2):

出てきたエラーメッセージを翻訳するとか検索にかければ分かると思いますが、コメントに書いた「`for`ループの中の`a += 0.1`にインデントが不足しています。」が該当しますね。

翻訳結果：

```
IndentationError: インデントされたブロックが必要です
```

検索記事例：
[Python “expected an indented block” エラー４つの原因・解決策](https://pisuke-code.com/python-fix-indentation-error/)
[【Python】expected an indented block エラー対処方法](https://kirinote.com/python-error-expectedanindentedblock/)

以下のようにすれば動作するでしょう。

```
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a += 0.1  #### インデントを追加する
a
```

Comment: ありがとうございます表示されました
a += 0.1
この列の先頭を一マス開ける必要があったということですかね？

Comment: はい、そうです。その辺は基礎的な知識なので公式のTutorialとかあるいはもっと初期的な入門とかの記事を探してひととおり学習しておくことを強くお勧めします。[Python チュートリアル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/), [Pythonチュートリアル on Jupyter Notebook](https://qiita.com/DeepTama/items/4bf9e3139471918eb0fe)